# I have a MacBook Air 13" and I would like to upgrade to OS Sierra

Tags: macos

I only have 5 GB of storage and I have already installed the installer but how much storage do I need on the HD to install it on there?

Comment: At even a rough guess you'll need double the size of the installer, but in any case you shouldn't be running your drive so full. They need space to 'breathe' Aim to keep 15% free at all times.

Comment: @Tetsujin has a great figure for when spinning drives were around. Now with SSD it’s more about just having enough space to work on temp files. Whether your SSD has 128 gb or 512 gb - the percentage free matters less than having enough. I’ll answer with our figure at work and from talking with lots of personal / home  past few years.

Answer (score 1):

15 gb of free space is my general rule for starting an upgrade. However, if you can free more, that’s always better. Since you have the installer, you can deduct that from my 15 gb figure.

Also, be sure you have a solid backup and maybe even test it before you install if you know you are potentially going to run out of working space as the installer runs, migrates all apps and settings and then cleans up old and temporary files.